# How to make set-input-method buffer-local

Tags: input-method, file-local-variables

I'm using Emacs 26.3.
How do I `set-input-method` to `latin-alt-postfix` at the top of
the buffer using the `-*- ... -*-` local-variables method?  There are only certain files that I want to do this for.

I looked in the manual and wiki, but the instructions are not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `eval` pseudo-variable to evaluate arbitrary code (which is dangerous, so be careful about accepting such files from others). See the description of specifying file variables in the manual: `C-h i g(emacs)Specifying file variables`.

Here's an example:

```
-*- eval: (set-input-method 'latin-alt-postfix) -*-

This is a test á á é ö etc.
```